# best_in_place datepicker not working (setting default format)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I can't change the default format of my datepicker. Maybe that's why best_in_place doesn't work because rails only accepts `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Currently, the datepicker shows but I can't save because of the format.

Am I doing something wrong in the .js file?

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
```

project.js

```
var ready;
ready = function () {

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });

    /* Activating Best In Place */
    jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
}
```

view

```
<td><%= best_in_place @project, :podate, as: :date %></td>
```